# How much can be achieved with a manual impact driver?

Tags: impact-wrench

Are the manual impact drivers which you whack with a hammer any use at all with anything but screws and small sockets? For example I need to shift a moderately rusty 15mm bolt which won't budge, on solid, flat bodywork - would one have any chance of helping? Some have a 1/2" drive so it sounds like maybe they can be reasonably beefy. It doesn't need to be fast and I'm aware it's not going to beat a powered driver.

[image: 1]

Comment: It does, thanks. It's probably worth a try, just for starting out. I did wonder how things would have gone without so many cordless tools.

Answer (score 1):

I have one of these and I don't recall that it ever worked for me.

These days the cost of an electric impact wrench is so low that I wouldn't fool with one of these.

Comment: Worked well for me, but back in the day when rechargeable impact wrenches did not exist. Also had the strength to hit it hard enough...

Comment: I agree with Solar Mike. They work fine so long as you have a heavy hammer, and the confidence to use it without breaking the fingers holding the driver (whether they are your own fingers or someone else's!). Tapping them gently with a 1 pound (500g) hammer is a complete waste of time.

Comment: @alephzero bbrings to mind "when I nod my head, hit it"...

Comment: This is one of those tools that requires practice to use, if you use it regularly it's fine, if you don't it's a source of frustration.

Comment: I find them most handy for screws. Like the screws that are stuck on brake rotors.

Comment: @GdD that applies to many tools... pun intended :)

Comment: Haha, thanks, so they aren't totally useless then. Definitely expected to need a good size hammer. Wonder how long it'll be until I catch my hand if I do end up trying one! A nice electric wrench will be on the wishlist though.